# How can I make setContent respect the 'white-space' property in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

Function setContent does not respect "white-space" css property

I try to use TinyMCE like plaintext editor. I use setContent function for loading content into TinyMCE and getContent function for getting content from TinyMCE. I try use parameter format: 'text', but I have problem with spaces.
When user writes into TinyMCE component, internal logic add nbsp and space char. And this is returned by getContent.
If I set css property white-space to value "pre-wrap" on root element (f.e.

), I can disable this. But in setContent function this is not respected and all multiple spaces are replaced to zero (in begin or end of row) or one (between words) space.

My TimyMCE setting:
`target: elementInstance, content_style: "p { ... white-space: pre-wrap; ... }", newline_behavior: 'linebreak', text_patterns: false, setup: (editor) => {...}`

What I need to set for respecting white-space property in setContent function?

Edit:
Here is CodePen link, where is it reproduce: [link](https://codepen.io/arny02/pen/LYgoEGq)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.